# change required field label if user misses it

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm using DotNetNuke to create a Website. I'm using a dynamic form module by DataSprings for user Information, and when the submit button is pressed it sends an email with the information. that all works. what I would like to do is cause the label of a required field to turn red if the user misses it. is this possible? I have not found anything in the manuals or online that has been helpful and nothing while exploring the settings of the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you find this answer it would be great to know! All it ever does is add your **Please enter _____ (field)" at the top or the bottom of the form. I think that's hard to find, but I know what I am looking for. Other folks probably have to hunt for it. It doesn't help that DataSprings doesn't have a more current user manual for the current version of Dynamic Forms!